# ads on an iframe

Tags: php, javascript, html

My website contains main iframe full of content but all content is loaded exclusively inside an iframe. I need to set any advertisement service but most of them needs to spider general content and not iframe content. Is there any supported method as set hidden divs or bookmarks on general html content? Ads can be on an iframe or general content but I do not already find full solution. Thank you

Comment: Do away with the iframe?

Comment: @Chris that would be great but for any other reasons I must keep the iframe. However I could set same content away or something like that. Any suggestions?